# Hiding worksheet's close,restore,minimize buttons

Tags: vsto, excel-2007, customization

I have a VSTO solution for Excel 2007 in which I override the Office menu button and the ribbon with controls of my own. I am using the visual designer to create the ribbon, but I am also overriding the default Office menu button implementation by injecting xml to hide the File, New, Open, etc. buttons (I do this by overriding the *RequestService* method in my workbook class).

However, there are 3 buttons that I would like to hide as well, namely the default close, minimize, and restore buttons found on the top right side of the sheet. They are not part of the ribbon as far as I can see.

I have their id's, *WindowRestore*, *WindowClose* and *WindowMinimize*, but I have no idea where to override their *Visible* property, since these commands are not part of the ribbon.

Any ideas?

Thanks